# Where is Reason's cons (::) operator?

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml, cons, reason

The cons (`::`) operator is a fundamental part of 1) writing recursive list functions in OCaml and similar languages, and 2) pattern matching on lists. However, I can't find anything in Reason's documentation concerning cons, and in the REPL, this throws an error:

```
Reason # let myList = [2, 3, 4];
let myList : list int = [2, 3, 4]
Reason # 1 :: myList;
Error: Syntax error
```

Is there a replacement for the cons operator?

Comment: What is Reason? I've not heard of it, and can't find anything on Google.

Comment: http://facebook.github.io/reason/

Comment: TIL. Thanks! I'd love to see a tag wiki about the language.

Comment: @MattBall was just released a couple of days ago, so it's very new. This question was mainly just to get Reason on the SO table. I've submitted a (brief) draft of the tag wiki.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ah, it's aliased as the "immutable list append" operator in Reason's [list of primitives](http://facebook.github.io/reason/#syntax-basics-primitives):

OCaml:

```
1 :: 2 :: myList
1 :: 2 :: [3, 4, 5]
```

Reason:

```
[1, 2, ...myList]
[1, 2, ...[3, 4, 5]]
```

Oddly, at least in the current version (0.0.6) you can use both syntaxes when pattern matching:

```
let head = fun lst => switch lst {
  | [] => failwith "Empty list"
  | [hd, ...tl] => hd
};

let head = fun lst => switch lst {
  | [] => failwith "Empty list"
  | hd::tl => hd
};
```